# Is it possible to create a foreign key with a condition?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have a table `site` that has a field `categoryid_root` and a table `category` which has the fields `id` and `parentid` I want to create a relationship between:

`site.categoryid_root` and `category.id` but with the condition that `category.parentid` is null is this at all possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible create a foreign key with a condition as you like. But you might use an intermediate table to simulate the condition. I call this table `category_root`. The `category_root` table will be updated *only* by triggers on `category` table. So you can create the foreign key between `site` table and `category_root` tables. No users must be have grants to update `category_root` to prevent inconsistencies. See diagram to see how the tables are related to each other.

[image: diagram]

```
create table category (
  id int auto_increment, parent_id int, name varchar(45),
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_parent foreign key (parent_id) references category (id) 
  on delete no action on update no action
) engine=innodb;

create table category_root (
  category_id int not null, 
  primary key (category_id),
  constraint fk_category_id foreign key (category_id) references category (id) 
  on delete cascade on update no action
) engine=innodb;

create table site (
  id int auto_increment, category_root_id int not null, name varchar(45),
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_category_root foreign key (category_root_id) references category_root (category_id) 
  on delete no action on update no action
) engine=innodb;
```

The trigger for insert is defined so when an new category without parent_id is inserted into `category` a new row is insert also into `category_root` table:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger t_category_ins after insert on category for each row
begin
  if NEW.parent_id is NULL then
    insert into category_root(category_id) values (NEW.id);
  end if;
end
$$
delimiter ;
```

The trigger for update is a little more complex:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger t_category_upd after update on category for each row
begin
  set @new_parent_id = NEW.parent_id;
  set @old_parent_id = OLD.parent_id;

  if (@new_parent_id is NULL) then
    if (@old_parent_id is not NULL) then  
      insert into category_root(category_id) values (NEW.id);
    end if;
  else  
    if @old_parent_id is NULL then
      delete from category_root where category_id = NEW.id;
    end if;
  end if;
end
$$
delimiter ;
```

Let try to insert some values:

```
insert into category(name) values('root1');
insert into category(name, parent_id) values('a', last_insert_id()), ('b', last_insert_id());
insert into site(category_root_id, name) values (1, "site1");

select * from category;
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | parent_id | name  |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |      NULL | root1 |
|  2 |         1 | a     |
|  3 |         1 | b     |
+----+-----------+-------+

select * from category_root;
+-------------+
| category_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+

select * from site;
+----+------------------+-------+
| id | category_root_id | name  |
+----+------------------+-------+
|  1 |                1 | site1 |
+----+------------------+-------+
```

If we try to add a site with a category_id with parent_id not null we got an error:

```
insert into site(category_root_id, name) values (2, "site1");

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`test`.`site`, CONSTRAINT `fk_category_root` FOREIGN KEY (`category_root_id`)
REFERENCES `category_root` (`category_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Thanks, so much for that. Must have taken you some time to write, your answer! I really appreciated it, answer accepted. :)

Comment: Answer it helps me to learn new things. Thanks for appreciating my answer.